# Как получить 2D координаты экрана от 3D точки?

Tags: c++, математика, 3d, irrlicht

На экран выводятся коробки. У них по 8 точек.
Мне нужно получить координаты коробки 2D - x y x1 y1.
Для вывода поверх коробки текста. 
текст принимает позицию rect<>(X , Y , X1 , Y1).

Мне нужна **формула**, по получении 2D координат 3D точки.

Вот  что имею: точку, матрицу проекции, матрицу вида, матрицу мира, viewport.
Нужны еще какие данные? например позиция и взгляд камеры?

```
core::vector3df point;

core::rect<s32> viewport = driver->getViewPort();
core::matrix4 matProj = driver->getTransform(video::ETS_PROJECTION);
core::matrix4 matView = driver->getTransform(video::ETS_VIEW);
core::matrix4 matWorld = driver->getTransform(video::ETS_WORLD);


core::quaternion point_qua(point.X ,point.Y , point.Z , 1);

// формула которую нашел на одном сайте
point_qua = point_qua*(matWorld*matView*matProj);

std::cout << "\nX=" << point_qua.X;
std::cout << "\nY=" << point_qua.Y;
```

Но координаты рассчитываются неправильно. Текст выводится в самом верхнем левом углу.

Answer (score 1):

Координаты видимой области в 3D от -1 до 1

Position = (matProj * (matView * matWorld)) * vertex

X = (( Position.X + 1.0 ) / 2.0)*Xres

Y = (( Position.Y + 1.0 ) / 2.0)*Yres

где Position - позиция вертекса после проецирования.
Xres и Yres - размер вьюпорта.

Координаты по Y могут быть перевернутыми в зависимости от API/